# How do I have multiple docker images for one project in one directory?

Tags: python, docker, deployment, docker-compose, dockerfile

For my current python project I have multiple 'programs' I want running  at a time (e.g. crawler, indexer, web server, postgresql server etc).
All of these python programs share some common modules in the same directory. I don't want to make different directories for each program as this would require I have multiple copies of these common modules in different places. I can't have multiple dockerfiles in the same directory for each program (I don't think?). I'm pretty sure I want to use docker-compose, but after I have built my seperate images from seperate dockerfiles.

What do I do in this situation? I'm pretty sure I am thinking about this all wrong because I can't imagine this is an uncommon problem.

Thanks!

Comment: do you want all the 'programs' running in one container or do you want each program in its own container?

Comment: @LhasaDad I am under the impression that you can only have (or maybe should only have) one program running per container. I would assume one program per container but if that isn't the typical way to do it, I am open to hear how.

Comment: depends on the architecture of what your trying to create.  if the programs need to communicate you will need to set that up with the containers if they are in different containers.  if there is one main way things talk to your functions then you could combine them in one.  your in the best position to decide that. 

if you want them all to use common code, etc.  you could put the entire set of code in the container image and have the entry point for each container be the module that you want to run in that container with the utilities in packages that the main modules can use

Comment: David Maze has given you a good way to go,  he is pointing out the two directions I was noting above.

Answer (score 9):

There are two straightforward answers in pure-Docker space.

The first thing you can do is package all of your code into a single image:

```sh
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["./main.py"]
```

You can override the command part at the `docker run` command or in a `docker-compose.yml` file, so run multiple containers off the same image.

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  crawler:
    build: .
    command: ./crawl.py
  indexer:
    build: .
    command: ./indexer.py
```

Or, you *can* have multiple Dockerfiles in the same directory

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  crawler:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.crawler
  indexer:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.indexer
```

and those Dockerfiles could be more limited

```sh
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY common common
COPY crawler crawler
COPY crawler.py .
CMD ["./crawler.py"]
```

Which approach to use depends on your code base.  If it's in an interpreted language, almost all of the code is shared, and the only real difference is the command you're running, then it's probably better to just have one image.  But if the library dependencies are significantly different for each dependency, or if you need to build a separate binary for each process, a separate image for each makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker compose in this scenario. Suppose you want to run two containers test and start in case of node application.

docker-compose.yml

```
version : 3

services:
  runApp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      -"3000:3000"
  testApp: 
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    command: ["npm","run","test"]
```

Dockerfile.dev

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR "/webapp"
COPY ./package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY ./ ./

CMD ["npm","run","start"]
```

Use `docker-compose up` for building image and running the container.